# How to disable automatic margins in LightningChart

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

Lightning chart (by [Arction](http://www.arction.com)) XY graph has automatic margins and they apparently adjust based on the fonts and axis values. I want to fix this size so I can better align the graph contents with other charts. I'd like to define them in pixels or Dips.

There's million of properties in the chart to touch, confused at this point. I've already tried to define ViewXY.Margins property but no luck. Must be something simple I'm overlooking now?

[Preferred margins rectangle in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvSZ4.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by setting chart.ViewXY.AxisLayout.AutoAdjustMargins = False. Then the ViewXY.Margins property takes over.